# Segmentation fault and out of memory error with STL in C++ code

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    // creating a stack of characters
    std::stack<char> stk;
    // exp will store the current read expression
    string exp;
    // number of tes cases
    int test;
    std:: cin >> test;
    // 1st for loop to be run up to value of test.
    // Added a few "cout"s for debugging for my own.
    for(int i=1;i<=test;i++)
        {
            cout<<"into the loop\n";
            getline (cin,exp);
            cout<< "have read the expression";
            std:: cout << exp;
            int explength= exp.length();
            cout << explength;
            // this loop will run up to the length of the string
            for(int j=0;j<explength;j++)
                {    // if the read character is a small case char,print it
                    if(exp.at(j)>=97 && exp.at(j)<=122)
                        std::cout << exp.at(j);
                    // Handling special symbols
                    // high to low :  (),/,*,-,+

                    else
                        {
                            if(exp.at(j)=='(')
                                stk.push('(');
                            else if (exp.at(j) == ')')
                                    {
                                        while (stk.top()!='(')
                                            {
                                            std::cout << stk.top();
                                            stk.pop();
                                            }
                                        stk.pop();
                                    }
                            else if (exp.at(j) == '^')
                                    {
                                        while (stk.top()!='^')
                                        {
                                            std::cout <<stk.top();
                                            stk.pop();
                                        }
                                        stk.push('^');
                                    }
                            else if (exp.at(j) == '/')
                                    {
                                        while (stk.top()!='/' || stk.top()!='^' )
                                            {
                                            std::cout << stk.top();
                                            stk.pop();
                                            }
                                        stk.push('/');
                                    }
                            else if (exp.at(j) == '*')
                                    {
                                        while (stk.top()!='*' || stk.top()!='/' || stk.top()!='^')
                                            {
                                            std::cout << stk.top();
                                            stk.pop();
                                            }
                                        stk.push('*');
                                    }
                            else if (exp.at(j) == '-')
                                    {
                                        while (stk.top()!='-' || stk.top()!='*' || stk.top()!='/' || stk.top()!='^')
                                            {
                                            std::cout << stk.top();
                                            stk.pop();
                                            }
                                        stk.push('-');
                                    }
                            else if (exp.at(j) == '+')
                                    stk.push('+');

                        }
                }
        std::cout << endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

This code take "test " number of expressions,one by one, process each expression as string and output its RPN to the console. 1st for loop is to read "test" number of expressions and 2nd for loop contains the logic to process each string. As this is my 1st STL program this code might contain some stupid function calls.

I am trying to change the given number of expression to Reverse Polish Notation using the stack in C++ STL. When I run this code on Ideone, the code enters the 1st for loop but does not print expression read in " string exp".When I run this on my windows pc ( G++ compiler ) ,it does not print anything inside the 1st for loop. It sometimes gives Segmentation Fault and some time Out of memory signal on Ideone. Too frustrated. I tried debugging it with GDB but no use. Any help will be appreciated. The problem statement for which I have written this code is : http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/
EDIT1 : Priority is High : (),/,*,-,+  : Low

Comment: It seems this expression is always true: `stk.top()!='/' || stk.top()!='^'` So, the loop will run infinitely and `stk.pop()` will eventually pop an object from an empty stack, i.e., you'll get undefined behavior. While fixing this expression *may* fix the odd behavior it won't fix the many logical problems.

Comment: How can you use character literals for plus, '+', but you can't use character literals for letters, such as 'A', 'a', 'Z', or 'z'?

Comment: An easier method to convert to RPN is to use a tree.  The prefix, infix or postfix conversion only depends on how you traverse the tree.  Search the internet for "prefix tree c++".

Comment: Also, wiki "shunting yard algorithm" for a straightforward way to convert infix to RPN.

Comment: I used "! stk.empty()" before popping the stack, still problem persists. Segmentation fault. Dietmar Kuhl

Comment: Sorry didn't get you exactly? Thomas matthews

Comment: Thanks for telling the easier methods but I think it would be great if I succeed in this then move try other algorithms on this problem. David Lively

Comment: Got Accepted with several attempts. Had logical mistake. Thanks to you guys.